# Why could a cheap electricity consumption meter break on modified square wave inverter?

Tags: inverter, square, meter

I have a number of cheap electricity consumption meters of which I used one on a modified square wave inverter I bought. They cost less than 15 EUR per piece so most likely they don't have much expensive electronics inside.

The meter said 200 V for a while (whereas the inverter I ordered should be 230 V). Then the LCD display went blank, I heard a fizzing sound and I smelt some burning component. I subsequently tested the meter in question on sine wave from electrical outlet and it didn't work in that case either, it just fizzed with a blank display and generated more burning smell. The inverter is working fine with other devices so that wasn't the issue.

Why would a cheap electricity consumption meter burn on modified square wave? They work on modified sine wave perfectly well.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the issue is with the power supply design in the meter. Computers, smartphone chargers and other electronics that require significant amounts of energy use switch mode power supplies always. Those supplies are intelligent: may work on both 120V and 230V AC, work on both 50Hz and 60Hz frequencies, don't care about slight over or undervoltage, and actually don't care about the waveform at all. Most likely those switch mode power supplies would work perfectly well on high voltage DC too.

This cheap meter may not contain a switch mode power supply because the cost of the equipment has to be kept low, and the device doesn't anyway consume lots of power.

A possible explanation is that the power supply of this meter consists of a bipolar capacitor, a full wave rectifier, a resistor, a diode and a second (likely electrolytic) capacitor.

This kind of power supply works by an idea where capacitor and resistor are connected in series and connected to 230V mains. The current (using a complex number phasor) is:

```
I = 230 V / (R + 1/(i*2*pi*f*C))
```

or if we want the strength of the current:

```
I = 230 V / (sqrt(R^2 + 1/(2*pi*f*C)^2))
```

The voltage across the resistor is then:

```
U = R * 230 V / (sqrt(R^2 + 1/(2*pi*f*C)^2))
```

...and a sine wave.

If a full wave bridge rectifier is connected between the resistor and capacitor, it will rectify the sine wave, creating a pulsing DC voltage.

If a diode and capacitor are connected in series across this resistor, the pulsing DC voltage becomes a constant DC voltage, picking the largest voltage across the resistor.

This system works as long as the current across the resistor is much larger than the current the device picks from the power supply. For example, a device could dissipate 1 W in the resistor and use 0.05 W of power, in which case the extra current the device needs doesn't affect the voltage much.

This power supply works only with a sine wave. If you feed any kind of square wave across it, the device will pick the voltage jump. So if the power supply is designed to give 5 V DC from a 230 V (RMS) AC sine wave, with 230 V modified square wave that has 325 volts peak, the device will pick the 325 volts peak jumps from the input and instead of 5 V DC, will give 325 V DC, most likely frying the second non-bipolar capacitor.

[image: RC divider power supply]

Comment: usually there's a resistor in series with C1,  it could even be that resistor that burned up.